# pytest overall result 'Pass' when all tests are skipped

Tags: pytest

Currently pytest returns 0 when all tests are skipped. Is it possible to configure pytest return value to 'fail' when all tests are skipped? Or is it possible to get total number passed/failed tests in pytest at the end of execution?

Answer (score 1):

There is possibly a more idiomatic solution, but the best I could come up with so far is this.

Modify this [example](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) of the documentation to save the results somewhere.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest
TEST_RESULTS = []

@pytest.mark.tryfirst
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call, __multicall__):
    rep = __multicall__.execute()
    if rep.when == "call":
        TEST_RESULTS.append(rep.outcome)
    return rep
```

If you want to make the session fail on a certain condition, then you can just write a session scoped fixture-teardown to do that for you:

```
# conftest.py continues...
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def _skipped_checker(request):
    yield
    if not [tr for tr in TEST_RESULTS if tr != "skipped"]:
        pytest.failed("All tests were skipped")
```

Unfortunatelly the fail (Error actually) from this will be associated to the last testcase in the session.

If you want to change the return value then you can write a hook:

```
# still conftest.py
def pytest_sessionfinish(session):
    if not [tr for tr in TEST_RESULTS if tr != "skipped"]:
        session.exitstatus = 10
```

Or just call through pytest.main() then access that variable and do you own post session checks.

```
import pytest
return_code = pytest.main()

import conftest
if not [tr for tr in conftest.TEST_RESULTS if tr != "skipped"]:
    sys.exit(10)
sys.exit(return_code)
```

Comment: Bulletproofed in this commit, thanks: https://github.com/myselfhimself/gmic-py/commit/222e1466d7ea3dd1d30b03e1d980cd58bb31145f

Comment: What does the line 

rep = __multicall__.execute() 

means?